# EF Core : Group by and select record with maximum value in each group

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-6.0, ef-core-7.0

I recently migrated from EF Core 6 to EF Core 7 and encountered an issue with a LINQ query that was working fine in EF Core 6 but fails in EF Core 7. The query involves grouping by a specific column and selecting the record with the maximum value in each group. Here is the original query:

```
var lastLogs = from l in _context.Db.data_point_logs
                               group l by l.log_type into grp
                               let maxBatchDt = grp.Max(p => p.batch_dt)
                               let logType = grp.Key
                               from p in grp
                               where p.log_type == logType && p.batch_dt == maxBatchDt
                               select new { p.log_type, p.batch_dt };
```

I understand that this type of query is not supported in EF Core 7, and I'm struggling to rewrite it efficiently. I would appreciate any assistance in rewriting the query to achieve the same result in EF Core 7. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How does it fail in EF 7?